# Is there a way to view how many days/months I have left on my free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Title says it all. I want to terminate my account just before free tier expires.

Comment: you can find it here. https://www.krunalparmar.com/Blog

Answer (score 2):

On the [Free Tier FAQ page](http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/) it says:

> **How do I know how much I’ve used and if I’ve gone over the free usage tiers?**
>   By logging into your [Account Activity page](http://aws.amazon.com/account-activity), you can see current and past usage activity by service and region, and download Usage Reports.